# How to remove wrong route from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am testing some examples in Rails 3, and somehow routing table ended up with wrong route.
This is the route that rails knows about

```
course_ad_student POST   /students/:id/course_ad(.:format)               students#course_ad
```

but in my Students controller method is this

```
def course_add
   #code
end
```

So the question is, how to remove that 'course_ad_student' route and place 'course_add_student' instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `config/routes.rb`. Find the line that's something like `post 'course_ad'` and change it appropriately.